# How force parity on AWS use public IP?

Tags: parity, aws

I have few mining parity on docker container in AWS instances.
Each AWS instance have private and public IP.
When I ask "parity_enode" it return enode address with private IP. I want it use public IP. Can I?

The reason use public IP is that nodes can not connect each other over private IP, only by public IP.

It seems I can do this by add all other nodes in bootnodes config.toml , but it will be better if they use public IP.